# CSS Columns - Shrinking window width and then expanding it only shows half the column-count

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, column-count

I'm using several media queries to control the amount of columns for different screen sizes. When the page loads, it works great. However I'm noticing that when I shrink the width of the window to almost nothing and then expand it to full width again, even though I've specified `column-count` to be 4, it only shows 2 columns, with a blank space where the right 2 columns should be. All the content is still there. Just squashed up into the left side. When I look at the current css rules being applied, it still says `column-count` is 4. I'm not sure what's going on. Tips please? Thanks!

Relevant CSS I'm using:

```
.reviews{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1vw;
    -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 4;
}
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/1o12sqsq/

Snippet:

```css
body{
    font-size: 16px;
    margin:0;

}
div, form{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-bar{
    color: white;
    background:black;
    margin:auto;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    /*border-bottom: white 3px solid;*/
}

.top-bar .oyster{
    font-size: 40px;

}
.top-bar ul{
    float:right;
}

.top-bar li{
    text-decoration:none;
    display:inline-block;
}

.top-bar a{
    text-decoration:none;
    color: white;
}
.top-bar ul li .item{
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right:20px;
}

.presenting{
    margin-top: 3vh;
    font-size: 2vmax;
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
}
.current{
    text-align:center;
    font-size: 10vmax;
}

.reviews{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1vw;
    -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 4;
}

.review{
    display:inline-block;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.question{
    color:brown;
    font-size: 1.3em;
}
.answer{
    font-size: 1.8em;
}
@media (max-width:797px){
    .reviews{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1vw;
        -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 2;
    }
}

@media (min-width:798px) and (max-width:1200px){
    .reviews{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1vw;
        -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 3;

    }
}

@media (min-width:1201px){
    .reviews{
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1vw;
        -webkit-column-count: 4; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
        -moz-column-count: 4; /* Firefox */
        column-count: 4;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>


<body>
    <div class="top-bar">
        <a href="/" class="oyster">Oyster</a>
        <ul>
        
            <li><a class="item" href="/review_form/">Write</a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="/profile/">andrew</a></li>
            <li><a class="item" href="/logout/">Log out</a></li>
        
            <li><a class="item" href="/archives/">Archives</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    
    <span class="presenting">Presenting this week's subject,</span>
    <h1 class="current">The Ocean</h1>
    <div class="reviews">
    
        <div class="review">
        4 by andrew
        
            <div class="question">What is your favorite spot?</div>
            <div class="answer">sad</div>
        
            <div class="question">Do you like the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">not really</div>
        
            <div class="question">What is your favorite spot?</div>
            <div class="answer">sleeping</div>
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="review">
        3 by andrew
        
            <div class="question">Would you like to live there?</div>
            <div class="answer">frog</div>
        
            <div class="question">What is your favorite spot?</div>
            <div class="answer">butts</div>
        
            <div class="question">What are some of the advantages of the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">none</div>
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="review">
        4 by andrew
        
            <div class="question">Would you like to die in the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">no</div>
        
            <div class="question">Do you like the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">naw</div>
        
            <div class="question">Every year many people drown in the ocean. How do you feel about that?</div>
            <div class="answer">god awful</div>
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="review">
        4 by andrew
        
            <div class="question">When was the last time you&#39;ve been to the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">I frankly do not remember.</div>
        
            <div class="question">Every year many people drown in the ocean. How do you feel about that?</div>
            <div class="answer">I feel god  awful of course! How could such a petty thing happen to such important people in our lives?! I simply cannot believe this!!</div>
        
            <div class="question">What are some of the advantages of the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">Probably none.</div>
        
        </div>
    
        <div class="review">
        3 by andrew
        
            <div class="question">Would you sing by the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">No sir!</div>
        
            <div class="question">Would you like to die in the ocean?</div>
            <div class="answer">Of course not, that is preposterous!</div>
        
            <div class="question">What is your favorite spot?</div>
            <div class="answer">My favorite spot would be to inside the a whale&#39;s tummy.</div>
        
        </div>
    
    </div>

</body>
```

Looks like it's a Chrome-specific issue since Firefox shows it all right.

Comment: Works fine on Firefox.

Comment: @ManojKumar Hmm yeah firefox does work okay. I've been using Chrome to see this issue. I thought webkit would fix Chrome's problem though?

Comment: It's how your media queries are setup.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn Chrome have problems with this, obviously - check known issues, BUT: it seems that -webkit-perspective:1; solves the issue. http://jsfiddle.net/1o12sqsq/3/

Comment: I rearranged your `@media` queries in order and appeared to correct the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/yongchuc/1o12sqsq/2/

Comment: Still kind of buggy, minimizing and maximizing back and forth.

Comment: @nevermind It doesn't seem to work :/

Comment: @ChrisYongchu Still doesn't seem to quite work either, but I've changed my media query order just in case of potential future problems.. Is it just me that it's not working for?

Comment: Yea, still buggy when resizing back and forth.

Comment: @pyramidface, you have checked updated fiddle? well, if user constantly resize window, after few times - chrome calculations are obviously wrong again...  But, it should (maybe?) work without extensive resizing... :)

Comment: @nevermind yeah, I took a look at your fiddle. The problem doesn't happen on load. It only happens when after the resize (max to really small, then really small to max).. The perspective line doesn't seem to change the behavior.

Comment: yea, that same behavior, even with `-webkit-perspective: 1;`.

Comment: Then i wouldn't worry too much... And, yes, maybe little javascript could help poor Chrome in this case... Maybe Chrome creators would consider this as a bug? https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95315?hl=en

Comment: @nevermind Okay, I reported it.